# Connect with DB2 from Java

Tags: java, database, db2, database-connection

I try to connect to db2 from java, here is my code:

```
    public class Db2Connection {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String jdbcClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver";
            String url="jdbc:db2://localhost:50001/TEST";
            String user="user1";
            String password="pass";


        System.out.println("before try-catch");
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("try");

            //Load class into memory
            Class.forName(jdbcClassName);
            //Establish connection
            System.out.println("before conn");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println("after conn");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(connection!=null){
                System.out.println("Connected successfully.");
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

To be clear, I add db2jcc.jar to my project and run code with valid url. Program cannot jump over line:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

I receive no errors or exception, application just not execute. I have no idea how deal with it, can anyone help me?

Comment: With that I got:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver

Comment: Your code works fine in my env. what is db2 server version  ?

Comment: Also could you change;   String url ="jdbc:db2://localhost:50001/TEST:" + 
  "retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;";

Comment: Version of my driver is 3.69.49, url with retrieve messeges gives me that output: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][10165][10036][3.69.49] Invalid database URL syntax: jdbc:db2://localhost:50001/TESTretrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815

Comment: add colon after 50001/TEST:

Comment: I added, got the same exception with String url="jdbc:db2//localhost:50001/TEST:", and same output, with no jumping over connection with my old url with extra colon

Comment: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver this is jdbc type2 connection,  com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver is type 4 connection, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0512kokkat/